# MySQL many-to-many: Insert into table and then into junction table?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, junction-table

I have 3 tables: `persons`, `places` and `person_place`.

Each person can have many favorite places, just as each place can be "favorited" by many persons/people.

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
//some fields omitted
);

CREATE TABLE places 
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
//some fields omitted
);

CREATE TABLE person_place 
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
personID int NOT NULL, //references persons.id
placeID int NOT NULL //references places.id
)
```

Let's say a user favorites a new place (by some web page).

How should I insert the new place and then get it's id in order to add the person_place row?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap the inserts inside a transaction and then use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the id of the last inserted item.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO places(name,address) VALUES('someplace', '...');
SET @last_inserted_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO person_place (personID, placeID) VALUES (1, @last_inserted_id)

COMMIT;
```

Comment: That's good. By the way, in case I need retrieve a join of the last inserted person_place and the last inserted places... How should I do that? Thank you.

Comment: After the commit, you can use the SET @last_person_place_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); and then use that id to do a join.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in MySQL you would use the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) function.